# Why is it that if you target a "Form" element in CSS, the properties apply only to the first child-element, and not all?

Tags: html, css

Here's what I mean.

```html
<div class="drop-down">
    <form action="/action-page.php">
        <label for="cars">Choose a Japanese car:</label>
        <select id="cars" name="cars">
            <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
            <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
            <option value="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
            <option value="Suzuki">Suzuki</option>
            <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
            <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
            <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.drop-down {
    background-color:white;
    padding:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:70px;
    padding-left:70px;
    font-size:20px;

    }
```

Now, the font-size applies to only the first child-element, which is the `label` element. Why is it that it doesn't apply to the rest of the child-elements, i.e. the `select` and `input`?

I have to separately target them to change their font-size. I thought that, if I target the parent element, the changes are going to cascade down to all the texts within the parent element, yet it only cascades down to the first child element.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser has it's own stylesheet (called *user agent stylesheet*).

If you inspect your `input` and `select` elements, you would see that browser overrides your style, since it has higher specificity:
[image]

Simply adding

```
input, select{
   font-size: inherit;
}
```

solves the problem.

It would be good idea to add css reboot like [this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap-reboot.css) or write your own in separate file. That would solve common problems and make styles less browser-opinionated.

Comment: So, "inherit" means that the element adopts the properties of its parent element? I still don't quite understand why are the properties of the parent element cascading down only to the first child-element, but not the other two? Is there something special about label, that the other two don't have? Why does the browser overrides the style only for the last two elements?

Comment: Yes, by adding `inherit` you explicitly tell browser to inherit font sizes from parent. As we see in picture, browser explicitly sets font size for input, which overrides implicitly inherited font size. By adding your own rules for input, select etc.. you override styles from user agent stylesheet, since they are applied at first.

Comment: @TaishoMori Font size for label works because user agent styles does not have font-size set for it. If you would nest labels or divs etc as deep as you want, your styles would still work, but if you add tag that has font size set by browser, you would need to style it explicitly. Every browser may style things by default differently. That's why it is a good practice to add css reboot (normallize) file. If you would generate HTML5 project with Webstorm, you would have it added by default.

Comment: I see. Good explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry i just have one last question. I just added the font-size inherit, and without even setting any font-size to the parent element, the font-size of both input and selector increased automatically. Is there some sort of default font-size being applied if no font-size is being set to the parent?

Comment: @TaishoMori default font-size for input on chrome is 13.3333px, when you've set `font-size: inherit` and if none of it's ancestors have font-size specified, your target elements inherited font-size of the root (html tag) which is equivalent to 1rem (unless you set it to different value). 1rem = 16px. So your input and select got font-size set to 16px instead of default 13.3333px.

Comment: I thought so myself. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining a separate CSS for `select`.

```
select {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

if you want the same style for both you can add it in style like `.drop-down, select {}` but it will make it worse as there is padding in your style for the label. it will be applied to the options also this will make your dropdown larger.

```css
.drop-down {
    background-color:white;
    padding:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:70px;
    padding-left:70px;
    font-size:20px;
}
select {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="drop-down">

        <form action="/action-page.php">

            <label for="cars">Choose a Japanese car:</label>
            <select id="cars" name="cars">
                <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
                <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
                <option value="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
                <option value="Suzuki">Suzuki</option>
                <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
                <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
                <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit">

        </form>


    </div>
```